# unfortunately (app_name) has stopped

Tags: android

I have created an app to navigate page from 1st activity to 2nd activity when submit button is clicked.But when i run my project am getting "unfortunately app has stopped". i have posted my code.. pls help me.

```
// main_activity ( 1st activity)

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:background="#ffff0000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="USER NAME"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="REGISTRATION FORM"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="CANCEL" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="PASSWORD"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="E-MAIL ID"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="ADDRESS"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

registrationform activity (2nd activity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffff0000" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="268dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="16dp"
        android:layout_y="238dp"
        android:text="PLACE ORDER"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="4dp"
        android:layout_y="141dp"
        android:text="YOU HAVE SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        tools:context=".RegistrationFormActivity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="90dp"
        android:layout_y="66dp"
        android:text="WELCOME"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pizza"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.pizza.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegistrationFormAcitvity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

main_activity java

```
package com.example.pizza;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addButtonOnClickEventListener();

    }
    private void addButtonOnClickEventListener()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Context context = MainActivity.this;
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent        (context,RegistrationFormActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

registration form java code

```
package com.example.pizza;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RegistrationFormActivity extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registrationform);
        addButtonOnClickEventListener();
    }
    private void addButtonOnClickEventListener()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

// logcat
```

02-11 02:46:20.049: D/gralloc_goldfish(1081): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-11 02:46:22.899: D/AndroidRuntime(1081): Shutting down VM
02-11 02:46:22.909: W/dalvikvm(1081): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a53b90)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): Process: com.example.pizza, PID: 1081
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.pizza/com.example.pizza.RegistrationFormActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.example.pizza.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-11 02:46:22.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 02:46:32.989: I/Process(1081): Sending signal. PID: 1081 SIG: 9
02-11 02:46:37.069: D/gralloc_goldfish(1107): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-11 02:46:45.309: D/AndroidRuntime(1107): Shutting down VM
02-11 02:46:45.309: W/dalvikvm(1107): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a53b90)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107): Process: com.example.pizza, PID: 1107
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.pizza/com.example.pizza.RegistrationFormActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at com.example.pizza.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-11 02:46:45.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: post your log-cat error...

Comment: Why you use AbsoluteLayout here as it already deprecated ...change it..and also use private or unique ids for view (i.e button, textview etc) ..otherwise sometimes R.java unable to save same view constants.change it also..

Comment: Post ur logcat. And don't use **AbsoluteLayout**. It is deprecated.

Comment: @user3295933 :- Its working properly!!!!!

Can you post your logcat error????

Comment: Just did a quick-manual debugging, and I also didn't see any problem with current code.

Comment: i have posted my log cat

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta : I have posted my logcat

Answer (score 0):

Edit your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.pizza.RegistrationFormAcitvity"></activity>
```

or

```
<activity android:name="RegistrationFormAcitvity"></activity>
```

and try again

Comment: That's not going to work without either the full package name or a dot.

Comment: @henry4343 The question is not asked by Simon.

Comment: sorry, it's my bad.. ha